# Supervised discretization with scikit-learn package

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wonder that if there is any way to do supervised discretization, such that fayyad-irani (considering entropy using class labels)?
I couldn't find supervised discretization method in sklearn package.

Any popular way will be helpful for me.

Comment: check if this can be useful for your requirements https://github.com/Morgan243/PyCAIM